# URL fragments and the BASE tag

Tags: javascript, html, url, fragment-identifier

I'm using the `<base>` tag in an application to simplify development.

I'm aware of the "*feature*" that occurs when an anchor is only a URL fragment, as in it routes to the `<base>` URL + fragment.

What can I do to circumvent that? I've never fudged with `window.location` or anything in Javascript, and rather than hack around for awhile at it, I assume someone knows of a quick-and-dirty, or an example.

Can this be circumvented? If so, please advise.

(*I hate asking questions that suggest no attempt has been made, but I've been searching/reading to little avail*)

(*Also; using jQuery, so any examples that would take advantage of vanilla Javascript or jQuery are welcome*)

---

**jQuery solution I hacked together**, not sure if its viable as a permanent solution though, thoughts?

```
$('a').each(function(index){
    if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#') == 0){
        $(this).attr('href', (window.location.href).replace(/#.*$/, '')
            + $(this).attr('href'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so, I think I understand the question now.

This has been tested in Google Chrome and Firefox.

Add this javascript at the end of the body:

```
base=document.getElementsByTagName("base"); 
base=base[0].href;

links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(index in links){
    if(links[index].href.indexOf(base+"#")==0){
        links[index].href=document.location+links[index].href.slice(links[index].href.indexOf("#"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use relative urls. The base tag won't affect urls like `/home` or `http://google.com`, but it will effect `about/us` or `users/12`

Comment: Thanks @Jcubed - I appreciate your opinion, however that does little to answer my question. I'm using generated relative URLs as a design choice for a several reasons, er go I am using the `<base>` tag, and fragment only anchors will break.

Comment: Essentially, on fragments only. `<base>` working on relative URLs is paramount though.