# How to edit the htaccess file

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote these in the `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php   
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)(/?)+$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But when I'm going to `site.com/user/nickname`, all content is loading relating `user` folder.
That is my `style.css` file, which located in root folder is not loading. I don't want to edit all my code.

**Example:** I have wrote these to all my code: `<img src="uploads/some_image.jpg">`. I don't want to change this to `<img src="/uploads/some_image.jpg">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to change this to `<img src="/uploads/some_image.jpg">.`

But that's what you should do. As an alternative you could use the `<base>` tag `<base href="/" />` within `<head>`. I would not advise you to solve this with more rewrite rules.

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem. When I'm using base tag links with hashtags are not working correctly. For example I have a modal window: http://yoursite.com/index.php#login. #login is not working as modal window, it's working as ordinary link.

Comment: Interesting. This makes the base tag less useful. Relevant SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779839/url-fragments-and-the-base-tag